# Does (Azure Logic Apps) Webhook support managed identities based authentication?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I am using a webhook action in my workflow but the subscribe (and unsubscribe) endpoints are (exposed by an API behind API Management) using AAD as authorization server.
Is there a way to use managed identities for obtaining authorized calls from the webhook action?

It has support for a 'Subscribe-Authentication' object but according to docs (here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-workflow-actions-triggers#connector-authentication) that doesn't seem to support managed identities.
I tried to configure *'Subscriber-Authentication'* to something like:

```
{
  "audience": "https://management.azure.com",
  "type": "ManagedServiceIdentity"
}
```

(as this works for 'Http Request' action but i got an error that 'ManagedServiceIdentity' is not supported).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my understanding for your description, it sounds like you want to use managed identities to obtain authorized calls from the webhook in a same AAD. However, the offical document [Authenticate and access resources with managed identities in Azure Logic Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/create-managed-service-identity) has said,

> To access resources in **other Azure Active Directory** (Azure AD) tenants
>   and authenticate your identity without signing in, your logic app can
>   use a managed identity.

So in your current scenario, the answer is no for using managed identity to access any resources in a same AAD, the only way is using `ActiveDirectoryOAuth` which be introduced at [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-workflow-actions-triggers#azure-active-directory-ad-oauth-authentication).

Comment: From what I have experienced, managed identities are an option even in the same AAD tenant, using a simple HTTP Request action. I can see that it is not possible from a webhook action -yet this seems like a lack of consistency to me...